# Is there a way to detect selected values in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to increase value of one column in selected rows whenever i `Select` items from table.

### Here is an example;

There is table `A` with `Text` and `Times` columns. When i insert values to that table `Times` column will be declared as `0`. When i `Select` rows i want `Times` column of selected rows increase by one.

Do you guys have any idea how to do that?

Comment: Based on SSMS, I assume you are using SQL Server, so I added the tag.  Look into `MERGE`.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger on `SELECT` doesn't exist, it makes any sense.

I suggest you to make a stored procedure, who execute your `SELECT` query and after this query, perform an `UPDATE` on the table.

Comment: Yeah that's what i thought afterwards. But how can i detect which rows are selected?

Comment: Just use the same WHERE condition on the SELECT and the UPDATE query. If you want something really precise, you can perform some SQL Dynamic, you pass the query in argument of your stored procedure.